# How to set a distance that rescales with the font

Tags: fontsize, lengths

I'm trying to set a distance which is relative to the font size.  The problem is that the distance is reused several times in the document, potentially in environments with a different font size.  In each case the distance should automatically rescale to retain it's proportion to the font size.  Unfortunately, simply specifying the distance in `em` or `ex` doesn't work because the distance is stored at the size of `em` or `ex` in the current font.  When the font changes, the distance is not updated accordingly.

Is there a way around this?  Ideally the solution should work under both LaTeX and PlainTeX.

Below is a M(n)WE which shows the current, undesired, behavior.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newskip\test
\test = 1em

\begin{document}

In each row, the lines should be the same length.

\rule{0.4pt}{1em} \rule{0.4pt}{\test}

{\tiny\rule{0.4pt}{1em} \rule{0.4pt}{\test}}

{\Huge\rule{0.4pt}{1em} \rule{0.4pt}{\test}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, this question duplicates that one.  I wonder why that one didn't pop up on my searches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the distance as a macro, rather than a length register:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\test}{1em}

\begin{document}

In each row, the lines should be the same length.

\rule{0.4pt}{1em} \rule{0.4pt}{\test}

{\tiny\rule{0.4pt}{1em} \rule{0.4pt}{\test}}

{\Huge\rule{0.4pt}{1em} \rule{0.4pt}{\test}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new command for the rule that resets the rule length each time you call it. Because a Plain-compatible solution was requested I used `\newskip`, but I include a LaTeX version commented out below it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newskip\ruleheight

\def\myrule{%
    \ruleheight = 1em
    \rule{0.4pt}{\ruleheight}%
}

% LaTeX version
%\newlength{\ruleheight}
%\newcommand{\myrule}{%
%    \setlength{\ruleheight}{1em}
%    \rule{0.4pt}{\ruleheight}%
%    

\begin{document}

In each row, the lines should be the same length.

\rule{0.4pt}{1em} \myrule

\tiny \rule{0.4pt}{1em} \myrule

\Huge \rule{0.4pt}{1em} \myrule

\end{document}
```

The bottom three lines show the output of the new command in different sizes.

[image]

Comment: While probably adaptable to my use case, the use of `\rule` in my MWE was simply to demonstrate the problem.  The distance actually gets used in a variety of contexts (sizing boxes, spacing elements, etc.).  As a result, I think egreg's solution below will be the more practical one.

Comment: Yes, defining it as a macro means that every time the length is called it is expanded only at that moment, so the current value of the length register would be applied. I was redoing by hand something TeX can already do automatically through macro expansion.